# Soap Client decorator doesn't throw SoapFault

Tags: php, decorator, soap-client, soapfault

I hope this is an easy one.

I have a `Client` class that extends `\SoapClient` (I use a custom Client because I want to log every soap call):

```
<?php

namespace App\Soap\Client;

class Client extends \SoapClient
{
    /**
     * @var ClientLogger
     */
     private $logger;

     /**
      * Client constructor.
      * @param $wsdl
      * @param array|null $options
      * @param ClientLogger $logger
      */
     public function __construct($wsdl, array $options = [], ClientLogger $logger)
     {
         parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
         $this->logger = $logger;
     }
...
```

This works perfectly fine, but there is an issue.

This client, in case of failure, doesn't throw any `\SoapFault` or any kind of `Exception`.

The only way I found is to do:

```
public function __construct($wsdl, array $options = [], ClientLogger $logger)
{
    try {
        new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
        $this->logger = $logger;
    } catch (\SoapFault $e){
        ...
    }
}
```

in this manner, in case of connection failure, a `\SoapFault` is thrown.

I think there is a better way.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dont you need a variable to pass the Exception object into the catch method?

Comment: The docs state `A SoapFault exception will be thrown if the wsdl URI cannot be loaded.` so I would say you are catching this exception properly except for the missing catch variable variable at `catch( \SoapFault $e )`

Comment: Ok in the code above I forgot to add (\SoapFault $e), but the issue is that __construct() does not throw Exception and I don't know why :(

Comment: @Mauro If you want it thrown then don't catch it or just [re-throw it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#example-282) with `throw $e;`